# Setting a cookie in angularjs then routing to a new page

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

Angularjs version 1.3.15

I've gone ahead and set a cookie using $cookieStore.put on my page "A" and now wish to redirect the user to a new page "B" to utilize that cookie. My question is

How do I redirect a user to a known route defined in angular that results in a full page load which will read the cookie header and allow me access to my cookie?

This is the only method that I've found that works:

```
testControllers.controller('aController', ['$window', '$routeParams', '$cookieStore',
    function($window, $routeParams, $cookieStore) {
        $cookieStore.put('test', 1);

        if ($routeParams.bounce && $routeParams.bounce != '') {
            $window.location.href = '/#/' + $routeParams.bounce;
            $window.location.reload(true);
        } else {
            $window.location.href = '/#/';
            $window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
]);
```

However it results in a double page load and is terrible. There has to be a better way.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Page "B" is using a different controller which utilizes a directive, but I'm viewing the Resources tab in Chrome - which is how I see the cookie isn't seen by the browser yet. The directive I'm looking to view the cookie in:

```
testControllers
    .controller('menuDirective', ['$scope', '$cookieStore',
        function($scope, $cookieStore) {
            $scope.loggedin = false;

            if ($cookieStore.get('loggedin')) {
                $scope.loggedin = true;
            }
        }
    ])
    .directive('mymenu', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/shared/menu/menuView.html'
        }
    });
```

Comment: How are you accessing the cookie on page B? Is it using a different controller?

Comment: Edited question to represent page "B" which contains a directive

Comment: Are you setting the cookie as soon as `aController` runs? And then does the `menuDirective` controller definitely get run after that? If you can reproduce this as a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) that would be helpful, I can't imagine why this is happening.

Comment: Seems to be a lot of work to do that. I resolved this by having an if statement at the top of my login controller that checked for the existence of the cookie, and if it was there to do a location.path change. Then in my POST response to login which sets the login cookie simply do a window.location.reload(true); which will trigger the page refresh, populate the cookie in the browser, and allows the if statement to be hit.

Comment: seems i can't close the question yet.

Comment: Well, if you still want our help, you need to give us something to play with to see where the problem lies. Think about it: when you get asked to help a coworker with a problem, how often do you need to get in and poke around, see all the code, to figure out where the problem is? We need to be able to do the same. Hence why you need a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in something like Plunkr. If you're not really willing to do that, then we can't help and you should close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by having an if statement at the top of my login controller that checked for the existence of the cookie, and if it was there to do a location.path change. Then in my POST response to login which sets the login cookie simply do a window.location.reload(true); which will trigger the page refresh, populate the cookie in the browser, and allows the if statement to be hit.